# Resources to learn about the fundamentals of computers?

Tags: computer-architecture

I have been wanting to learn more about how computers work. Getting way ahead of myself, but as in would it be possible to build a computer from scratch by myself? I mean build the individual parts and everything that goes into it. I understand that this question is more on the side of computer engineering but I though I might get some valuable response here. I mean I wanna know from the ground up how a computer works. As per my naive understanding at the moment: If everything on my screen right now is just a bunch of pixels, how does the computer know that I have clicked on a certain region and then complete a certain process. Like when I close a window, how does the computer know to change the pixels to something else?

I am not able to articulate what I am trying to say. But like how a does a computer work from the complete basics. When trying to learn about these things, most often people start talking about CPU'S and other related hardware. While I understand how all those are necessary for a computer for function, how did all of this start out? I found this [post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/135961/how-do-computers-really-work-at-the-most-basic-level) on here before that seems relevant.

Could you recommend some resources for learning about this more. Could you maybe give a short introduction to it? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/3390/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/126818/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/22314/755

Comment: "How does it know to change the pixels" is a software thing - the software somehow knows that you clicked a certain place, and then it somehow tells the video display to change the pixels. Two separate pieces of hardware. Actually, it just knows that you clicked. Hardware doesn't even have a mouse cursor position - ask anyone who's played FPS games.