# Relation between hardware and software

Tags: computer-architecture

I'm very interested in computing and programming. I have done a lot of programming with different languages although I have a question nobody was able to answer until now.

I question myself how is software related to hardware. to be more specific what are the basic mechanisme which make it possible for hardware to understand software code?

**for example** : when you put on the computer it starts at a certain point in the register and feeds it into the apu. afther that I'm stuck ....

edited the question

Comment: You seem to want to know how computers work. The answer is in some sense simple, in another sense complicated. I recommend you [start here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3390/how-does-a-computer-work). Community votes, please: is this a duplicate?

Comment: Note also that you should as *one* question per post, and one that can be answered in a somewhat concise way. Currently you are asking for a book. Community votes, please: is this too broad?

Comment: @raphael thx for your answer, i will look into it (i looked at it wow thanks so much !!) :D on behalf of your second comment. i have posted several questions about doxygen and seperated them all in single questions and got the comment : isn't that a lot of questions about the same program and i should bundle it in one post. now i have to make seperated post ? please help ?

Comment: That was probably on a different site. To be clear, what we appreciate is that every post contain *one* question. Only after having received, read and understood answers to that one would you post the next, at least if they are not completely independent. That prevents that answers to simultaneous questions contain lots of redundant material, which happens a lot when learners have deeper problems they can not quite articulate.

Comment: @Raphael thx for the clarification !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a difficult question to answer. I would comment if I could.
The first problem is that you have not defined what you mean by a computer? Are you talking about the electrical based computers we know today or are you also including mechanical computers in your question? Here's [a wiki link about the Difference Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_engine). The difference engine is completely mechanical but you can still technically 'program' it although it does not directly follow the paradigms of today.

Most parts of your question relate to one specific problem: How does the processing unit of a computational device work in a general way in accordance to the modern idea of software? I will give a general overview of what processor do.

A computer has three general operations: input (The input the user puts in, which includes data and what operation is wanted to be done), processing (the processor taking the input and operating on it) and output (what information is returned to the user). So what is inputted into a computer at the lowest level is some data and what is called an op-code or instruction. This is instruction is part of a collection stored in the processor (either electronically or via some other physical means) which has a defined algorithm associated with it. These instructions are considered 'basic' or low level. When something much more complicated is required to be processed, it is broken down into small parts which use these instructions to produce the desired computation in the end. Mechanical processors, specifically gearing based systems work in a similar way but accept input differently. The gears shift according to an algorithm to produce a result from a specific sequence of gear shifts initially (which is the input).

[Here's a link to a Intel Lesson Series on Microprocessors](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/education/k12/the-journey-inside/explore-the-curriculum/microprocessors.html)

[Another explanation of the CPU](http://homepage.cs.uri.edu/faculty/wolfe/book/Readings/Reading04.htm)

From what I can gather the software you are talking about are the programs you see running on a computer. These are considered to be high level software, which are very complex when looking at this software from the perspective of a processor. Essentially the tools used to make this software and the software itself is broken down into a set of instructions for the processor to process at some point in the execution chain. With modern software there are many layers of abstraction to get from the processor to what the user sees. See this Wikipedia article about abstraction (It's the most comprehensive I could find): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science)

Modern compilers such as gcc take human readable code and turn that into executable code which the operating system then executes. During execution the operating system will call processor instructions (which is a few abstraction levels down) in accordance to the executable code which the compiler produced.

Comment: thanks @TRex22 you very much !! i understand it much better now :D